# how to get the next occurrence of Monday (Dates) using typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date, datetime

I am trying to get the next occurrences of 13 Monday dates using **typescript**.

I have tried with the below code, But getting only next Monday date. I need to get remaining Monday (dates) at the same time I need to add to an array as well.

I am using angular 4 and typescript for the same.

Could any please suggest any idea of this problem.

***below is my code***

```
  var mondayDate = this.dateFrom;
  var dateFrom = mondayDate.setDate(mondayDate.getDate() + (7 - mondayDate.getDay()) % 7 + 1);
  var firstMonday = new Date(dateFrom);
  -----------
  -----------
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Using moment js we can generate these days.

Comment: @shashidhara sorry i cannot use the moment.js

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you.

moment.js is also a good option

```js
//d can be any date
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() +1);
 

function getNextMonday(anyDate){
  var dayOfWeek= anyDate.getDay();
  var aux=dayOfWeek?1:-6; //if it is sunday or not
  var nextMonday= new Date();
  nextMonday.setDate(anyDate.getDate() - dayOfWeek + aux +7)
  return nextMonday;
}


console.log(getNextMonday(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, final result will be in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

```js
var fromDate = new Date(2018, 10, 28); //28/11/2018
var toDate = new Date(2018, 11, 28); //28/12/2018

var tempDate = fromDate;
var noOfDays = Math.round((toDate-fromDate)/(1000*60*60*24));
var noOfWeek = noOfDays/7;
var mondays = [];
for(var i =0; i < noOfWeek; i++){
  tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate() + (7 - tempDate.getDay()) % 7 + 1);
  if(tempDate < toDate){
    mondays.push(tempDate.getDate()+"/"+(tempDate.getMonth()+1)+"/"+tempDate.getFullYear());
  }
}
          
console.log(mondays);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple TypeScript solution

```
this.today = new Date();
this.nextMonday = new Date();
this.nextSunday = new Date();

// Use 1 for Monday
this.nextMonday.setDate((this.today.getDate() + (1 + 7 - this.today.getDay()) % 7));
// Use 7 for Sunday
this.nexySunday.setDate(this.today.getDate() + (7 + 7 - this.today.getDay()) % 7);
```

As you can see the first number is the day you want (1: Monday, 2: Tuesday,... 7: Sunday).